# Facebook login was disabled and now it throws errors

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-ios-sdk

We have Android and iOS apps with integrated Facebook login. Recently Facebook disabled our app because "During Login, your app is crashing or hanging excessively". The problem however is not in our app's source code, but somewhere in our FB app configuration. When we try to log in with a Facebook account that is a developer or administrator in our FB app, we get an error from FB 'Unsupported request'. When we try to log in with any other Facebook account, including Facebook test accounts, we get an error "App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode....". See attached screenshots.

Note that our app was live and everything was working fine for years, until recently it was disabled.

Does anyone have an idea what might be the issue?

[image: screenshot unsupported request]

[image: screenshto app not setup]

One thing that I notice in our FB app configuration in the Permissions and Features section, is that the 'email' and 'public profile' permissions have 'Standard Access'. When I try to change it to 'Advance Access', it asks me for my password, but then the access level doesn't change. It stays 'Standard Access'.

[image: screenshot FB app settings]

We are using very up-to-date SDK versions:

[image: screenshot API versions]

Comment: _"We are using very up-to-date SDK versions"_ - well at least for the iOS version that's not really true, is it?

Comment: The version of the iOS SDK in our app is 9.1.0. It is not the latest, but has been released on 2021-02-25, so it is new enough. Correct me if I am wrong, but I think that anything above version 8 should be good. At least in their Android update guide, the code they give is: "implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[8,9)'"

Comment: It seems I have a similar case. Recently disabled app from FB and currently we are at appeal process. Although I've follow the FB guideline process, app still get "Unsupported request" error during FB login. It seems that FB Login through web SDK it just doesn't work. But under these circumstances appeal from FB won't won't be accepted.

Comment: I have also a similar case. With iOS sdk 12.1.0 that is the latest. And it seems that is a problem of SDK or Facebook backend for the specific appid because I tested same app with no change in my code but with new facebook app id to login and it worked. But facebook support really not help at all because they run a test login flow and they respond two times that isn’t working nevertheless they caused the error.

Comment: @R3dHatCat We were fixing our problem with them during 2 months and all this time our app was blocked. They couldn't check our app because of their different location where our test user were blocked by FB (because of different location) -_- And, yeah, no reasons were given. I used VPN to create a user in their location, it worked, but now we have problem with checking data usage. To unblock my app I should pass data usage verification but I can't because my app is blocked. :\ And no other way to fix it without FB support, unfortunatly.

Comment: @MarinaBudkovets Unfortunately facebook support don't help at all, no technical answers or help from them. The way that we continue for this situation was to make a new Facebook App and change our app to work with the new one. (unfortunately the already live app can't work so the users need to update)

Comment: Check if Facebook sent you any email on the address provided in your App Dashboard. They might have disabled you app. If that's the case, you won't be able to access the login feature through the SDK since the app is disabled by Facebook. In order to make it work, Facebook needs to enable it again. You can still test it after upgrading the SDK by using test users (you can create them under Roles menu section)

Answer (score 2):

In our case, any communication with facebook didn't help. They can't respond to technical level and explain why and what is the error message from their part.

So the solution for us was to make a new Facebook App and set up our apps to use this new FB App ID and release them.

- (this means that all the users that have our app will need eventually to go update so they can use the facebook login)

This way Android and iOS worked with latests SDK 12+

Answer (score 1):

We solved this by using older versions of the Facebook SDK.
For Android we switched back to version 11.3.0. So in build.gradle we have:

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:11.3.0'.

For iOS we had to switch way back to version 8.2.0. So in Podfile we have:

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit' , '~> 8.2.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 8.2.0'

It appeared that the problem is in the "openId" permission, which the Facebook SDK is adding silently behind the scene to the list of requested permission. On iOS we found that this is done in class FBSDKLoginManager.m in method -(NSDictionary *) logInParametersWithConfiguration: (FBSDKLoginConfiguration  FBSDKServerConfiguration)

We managed to test where the problem comes from on an Android device, which doesn't have the Facebook App installed. In that case, when you try to login, the Facebook SDK opens a browser and the URL can be inspected. We saw the "openId" parameter in the URL path parameters. With that parameter in the URL we had the error message from Facebook. Then we removed the "openId" parameter from the URL and resubmitted the request and it succeeded. That gave us the clue to search where in the Facebook SDK this "openId" parameter gets added to the request and in which version of the SDK it first appears.

Comment: Nice debugging session! Unfortunately, this won't work for long.. as Facebook will deprecate SDK version 8.2 and below on January 19th, 2023, as stated on their blog post: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2021/01/19/introducing-facebook-platform-sdk-version-9/

Answer (score 0):

happen to me too `During Login, your app is crashing or hanging excessively` and now it get disabled by facebook and we still can't figure it out what is the source of problems

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).